# At what temperature should one bake a coconut crust for a Hershey Bar Pie?

Tags: baking, pie, temperature, crust

Today I plan to bake a hershey bar pie.

I have done this in the past but never really get the crust to turn out like I expect. I am wondering if I am not cooking it at the correct temperature since all the other aspects of making the crust have been followed.

What is or are the recommended temperatures for doing this?

Comment: How are you making the crust now (ingredients, steps, temperature)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend makes coconut crusts all the time and she bakes them at 350 degrees.  But AllRecipes.com bakes their crust at 325 degrees for 15 minutes.

Comment: When I read it I thought exactly 325. +1 for getting there first.